# How many jumbo double yolk eggs should I substitute for large eggs?

Tags: baking, eggs, cake, measurements

If I only have jumbo double yolk eggs, should I reduce the amount of eggs called for in cake recipe (which calls for large eggs), and if so, by how much?

Answer (score 3):

The formulation I use;
1 jumbo double yolk egg = 2 yolks + 1 white